# Actual and Formal arguments differ in length - don't know why

Tags: java, constructor

I'm a beginner Java programmer, and I have two simple files to solve a simple math problem. One of them calls the other, which calculates the factorial of the number (e.g. 4! = 24). For some reason, I can't call the `Factorial` constructor.

Here is the calling class:

```
package Permutations;
import Permutations.Factorial;

public class Permutations {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("There are 10 students. Five are to be chosen and seated in a row for a picture. How many linear arrangements are possible?");
        System.out.println(new Factorial(10) / new Factorial(5));
    }
}
```

Here is the `Factorial` class

```
package Permutations;

public class Factorial {
    public long Factorial(int num) {
        long result = 1;
        for(int i = num; i > 0; i--)
            result *= i;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Permutations\Permutations.java:7: error: constructor Factorial in class Factoria
l cannot be applied to given types;
                System.out.println(new Factorial(10) / new Factorial(5));
                                   ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Permutations\Permutations.java:7: error: constructor Factorial in class Factoria
l cannot be applied to given types;
                System.out.println(new Factorial(10) / new Factorial(5));
                                                       ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
2 errors
```

I could change it to a static method, but then I would have to call it with `Factorial.Factorial(num)` rather than `new Factorial(num)`, which would be inconvenient.

I have no idea why this is happening. Please help!

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers. I've figured out what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, what you have written is not a constructor. Constructor don't have return type.

So, in absence of constructors, your class has defined a default constructor that takes no arguments (which is the one the compiler dutifully tells you to use, since you try to create a new instance).

Solutions:

1. use a static method instead of trying to use instance. Seems the most practical approach
2. if you must use a class because it is homework, define both the constructor and a `getFactorial` method. The `getFactorial` may have a return type, and provide you the value that you want. You will have to use it in something like that

   ```
   Factorial fac1 = new Factorial(5);
   System.out.println("Factorial " + fac1.getFactorial());
   ```

   or even

   ```
   System.out.println("Factorial " + (new Factorial(5)).getFactorial());
   ```

   Usually the first version is prefered for readability.

Comment: Pretty sure those parentheses are unecessary

Answer (score 1):

There is no constructor in your class that takes a long argument. You are mistaken by the fact that this method is a constructor:

```
public long Factorial(int num)
```

Constructors don't have a return type. As you have mentioned a return type to above signature, hence it has become a normal method and not a constructor.

And when there is no constructor written in class, then compiler provides a no parameter constructor and hence it is throwing an error with reason:

> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Answer (score 0):

Constructors cannot have user defined return type:
They can be just:

```
public constructor(parameter p){
// TO DO SOMETHING
}
```

And you cannot pass value in `System.out.println()` as `new Something();` . Only methods can be passed like that which have some return type.

Answer (score 0):

When you declared

```
public long Factorial(int num)
```

, this isn't a constructor for Factorial, since it's typed as long. A constructor would have to be declared as follows:

```
public Factorial(int num)
```

Since you haven't declared a constructor, the only existing constructor is the default one, which takes no arguments, and so when you call

```
new Factorial(10)
```

you get an error, since new Factorial takes no arguments with the only existing constructor.

Edit: Also, even if you fix that, you can't take

```
new Factorial(10) / new Factorial(5)
```

because division isn't defined on factorials.

Answer (score 0):

First please refer to the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) for naming packages and classes and methods.

Second you mixed up constructor and methods of a class. A constructor has the same name as the class and no return value. It is used with the new keyword to generate an instance of the class.

You have written a method called "Factorial" with the return type int (see coding guidelines why you should use lower case). Since your class is missing a constructor Java has added a default one with no parameters. But you try to call an constructor with an int parameter. This is why you get the error.

To call your method Factorial on the object Factorial you would need to generate a new instance and call the method with the int param. Like this:

```
int fact = new Factorial().Factorial(5)
```

However for your example an object creation is not needed so maybe go for a static method factorial instead.